# How can vxfs backup superblock data be recovered in Redhat?

Tags: backup, redhat, superblock

While Veritas CFS solution is installed in mail server, disk I/O error is happened.
In order to solve this problem, the disk setup command is used but the head data(31MB) is cleared.
My question is how many vxfs(Veritas File System) backup superblock data is existed in Redhat?
If backup superblock as well as superblock is collapsed and can’t be recovered, how can it be created?